# Laravel `orWhere()` function

Tags: database, laravel, query-builder

I am building an query where i want to get the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE color = 'white' OR color = 'red'
```

This color is a filter and based on the selection of the customer it adds the red or white color filter, or even more colors.

So i tested with:

```
    if(isset($input['filter']['color'])) {
        $query->where(function($where) use ($input) {
            foreach($input['filter']['color'] as $color) {
                $where->where('color', array($color));
            }
        });
    }
```

But this results in:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (color = 'white' AND color = 'red')
```

Any one how can tell me how to solve this? I have tested some stuff but i don't get the result i want. Color is just on filter, there are more filtering options.

So for example an filter query could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (color = 'white' OR color = 'red') AND (used = 'Y') AND (size = 1 OR size = 2) etc..
```

Erwin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use an `orWhere` filter:

```php
if (isset($input['filter']['color'])) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($input) {
        foreach ($input['filter']['color'] as $color) {
            $query->orWhere('color', $color);
        }
    });
}
```

Or just use `whereIn`:

```php
if (isset($input['filter']['color'])) {
    $query->whereIn('color', $input['filter']['color']);
}
```

Comment: Never though about the where in function. Thats a way simpler solution. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: IN is what I was looking for but great to find a where in solution. Is there something like where in like?